# Resource ID In Android Library Project

Tags: android, open-source, shared-libraries

I wanna include an open-source project in mine. But after check the "is library" option, some thing like "case R.id.menu_search:" can't be compiled. Should I replace them with its contant values, or how can I include it?

```
    case R.id.menu_search: // ! case expressions must be constant expressions
        onSearchRequested();
        return true; ...
```

Comment: change case to if...else statements. In eclipse, you can do that by pressing ctrl + 1 when the cursor is on the case keyword.

Comment: if(id == R.id.menu_search) {...}? But all R.id.menu... is not recognized after check option "is library".

Comment: case android.R.id.home can be recognized correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to change your `switch()` statement to `if()`/`else if()`/`else` statements. `R.id.menu_search` is not a constant (`static final`) and cannot be used in a `case` statement. That is because `R.id.menu_search` is coming from your Android library project. `android.R.id.home` *is* a constant, because that is part of the OS and is not changing.

Comment: Why are id's in a module not static final, but when you have them in your app's code, all R.java id's are final...

Comment: @Boy: I do not remember the reasons off the top of my head -- sorry!

Comment: @Boy When multiple library projects are combined, the actual values of the fields (which must be unique) could collide. See http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields