# Import android-support-v7-appcompat within a library project causes: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I have an Android project in which I want to generate two versions, one paid and one with advertising. According read on Stackoverflow, one way to do this is to create a parent project and create 2 child projects who imported the parent as a library. Also I use appcompat, so the hierarchy is as follows:

[image]

The problem is that the R class does not compile due to an error, which I can not find. But when the parent project did not configure as library ("Is library unchecked") everything works fine. Here the pictures:

[image: appcompat project in eclipse]

[image: appcompat build path]

[image: parent project as library and import appcompat and other libs]

[image: errors]

[image: more errors]

Hopefully you can help me, thanks in advance.

Edit: mark's answer resolved the problem with android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text, but I still have errors with the R class, example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my English.

Replace the error line with this:

> EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

Comment: Thank's. That solved the problem android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text, but I still have errors with R class :(

Comment: It is an ID of a menu item. I edited the main question with more details.

Comment: mark, android.R.id.save doesn't work. In fact, R class doesn't exists in bin folder.

Comment: Can you send to me the error that writen to you now?

Comment: mark, I solved the problem, I wrote the details as an answer of the main question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In fact, mark's answer solved part of the errors, but, after reading this post [Resource ID In Android Library Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475166/resource-id-in-android-library-project), solved the problem with menu id's.

Thanks.