# How to solve error: "Resource IDs cannot be used in switch statement in Android library modules"

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I imported a Android project created by someone else into my project as a library module. I get the following error even after cleaning and rebuilding project:

> Constant expression required Resource IDs cannot be used in switch
> statement in Android library

[image]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005205/what-causes-constant-expression-required-errors-for-the-generated-r-id-xxx-val.

Comment: Replace it by if else statement. and visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475166/resource-id-in-android-library-project

Comment: Try cleaning your project and build again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your main problem here is that `switch` statements require constant values as comparators, be it either a literal value e.g. `1`, `"hello"` or a `final` variable declared at class level. Android `R.id` values have **not** been constant since API 14, as stated in that error message, so therefore cannot be used as part of a switch statement.

Your alternative would be to use `if else` statements as they do not require constant values, like so:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.something) {
    // Do something
} else if (v.getId() == R.id.something_else) {
   // Do something else
}
// Repeat however many times required
else {
   // Default value
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. one trick for ease: alt+enter on switch statement to replace it automatically by android studio

Answer (score 7):

You can set a tag for each view and use the tag in the switch case. Something like this:

In your view:

```
...
android:tag="test" />
```

In code:

```
switch(v.getTag()){
    case "test":
    // Do Something
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try pressing F4 on one of those items:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class anim {
        public static int abc_fade_in = 0x7f010001;
        public static int abc_fade_out = 0x7f010002;
```

They are not declared final.

So you need to use if-else statements not switch.

As an historical note, they used to be final in older versions of Android...

Details here:
[Switches Suddenly Broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840914/android-resource-ids-suddenly-not-final-switches-broken)

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, `R.id.someId` are not final variables (static final int), therefore you cannot directly use `switch` clause on them. Instead rewrite whole switch with classic

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.openPictureBtn) {
 ... 
} else if (v.getId() == R.id.openCameraBtn) {
 ... 
}
```

conditional statements.